# Почему слово "сплитуха" не так широко распространено в разговорной речи?

Tags: этимология, лексика, разговорная-речь

В последние годы это слово часто слышу от своих знакомых, особенно летом. Почему это слово не так широко распространено в разговорной речи россиян, как в случае со словом "звуковуха" и т. п.?

Answer (score 0):

сплит – многозначное слово https://otvet.mail.ru/question/21682749
англ. split — разделение / раскол, а еще и соединение / сплетение
сплит - дробление акций обращающихся фондовом рынке - финансовый термин
сплит - музыкальный альбом с двумя (или более) исполнителями - термин звукозаписи
сплит система – устройство кондиционирования воздуха, состоящее из двух блоков - технический термин
Добавление суффикса -уха (сплитуха) позволяет «укоротить» двусловный технический термин и придать ему выразительности (в пределах разговорной лексики). Подобные попытки словообразования предпринимались и будут предприниматься в дальнейшем, благо вариантов (суффиксов) еще предостаточно: сплитёха, сплитяха, сплитушка, сплитюня, сплитЕма, сплитюра, сплитяра.
К примеру https://author.today/reader/114849/911539: «А там сплитяра… Там телек, и мой козырный, продавленный чуть ли не до ножек диван».
Возможно, что такое обилие возможных вариантов не позволяет выделиться и закрепиться (в речи) одному из них.
Впрочем, в качестве наименования  для кондиционера викисловарь уже фиксирует (сленговое) «кондей», он же «кондёр» / «кондишн».